# Account-edit: "changing picture" ("for all communities") changed(=overwrote) also all profile-descriptions

Tags: support, user-accounts, user-profile

*Thank you all - I've got nearly everything using the google cache. Current problem resolved. **(But how can I prevent doing the same mess next time when I want to change my profile picture again?)***

---

Uhh, that was really a mess. Today I changed my profile giving it a nice picture; at the end of the screen there are two buttons: change only here / change on all communitites. If I recall right then when I clicked "change on all communities" there was, as somehow expected, a notification "changing all pictures , ok?" . However, if not then, but at least with the next update (of a nicer picture) I found that also my (community-specific) personal descriptions were overwritten by that of the math-community description.

That's really an unfriendly measure... Is there now any possibiblity to recover the personal descriptions of the other communities? Or do I need to delete them all/rewrite them all with the appropriate texts? Urrkks...

Comment: I hope somebody will have a better suggestion but a possibility (involving lot of manual work if there is many accounts) would be check whether some of the information can be recovered from [internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http://german.stackexchange.com/users/248/gottfried-helms) or Google cache. I copied [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19870120#19870120) what I saw in Google cache when searching for [gottfried helms site:german.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=gottfried+helms+site:german.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Martin:thanks! I've also just started to understand how to use the google cache and have already two entries recovered. Hope I'llget them all...

Comment: I you're using Chrome, you can type `cache:URL` in the address bar (eg. `cache:math.stackexchange.com/users/1714/gottfried-helms`) and it will automatically gives you the google-cached version, if it exists.

Comment: @Najib: this seems -at least: formally- to be possible also with the firefox. (Only, that google cache seems now to be empty)

Comment: Did you also update your math account's personal descriptions? From [this announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239619) it appears that the "Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities" button should only copy _changed_ entries to all of your SE profiles.

Comment: @Arthur - yes, that's exactly what I remembered. But no, I didn't change anything else, at least not consciously... And I think I've seen the remark in the save-box concerning what it was saving only the *first time* when I changed the picture; I've the vague feeling that I didn't see this remark when I updated the picture the second time...